# Require Help and Opinion on B2 visa reapplication

Tags: b1-b2-visas

I had applied for B2 visa and had interview a week ago in Chennai, India.
My Husband has B1 visa and has travelled to US multiple times. I wanted to visit him this time for 1 month duration, have vacation and return back.
I was asked the below questions

1. What is your purpose of travel ?
   A: Tourism
2. Why are you travelling to US?
   A: I told them the above mentioned statement(My Husband has B1 visa and has travelled to US multiple times. I wanted to visit him this time for 1 month duration, have vacation return back.)
3. Where are you planning to stay?
   A: Since my husband is staying in Company provided accommodation, I am staying with my friend 'xxx' in the address 'yyyy'.
4. Where do you work ?
   A: Answered with my company name.
5. Where does your husband work?
   A: Answered with his company name.
6. Who is sponsoring your trip?
   A: Self Sponsor.

And after this my application was rejected with 214(b). 
Previously I have travelled to nearby Asian Countries as tourist and returned before the given time. I am working for an MNC with really good salary. I do have my home, family, job everything in India. But I did not tell this things because it was not asked. Also its mentioned in all Visa help sites not to answer more than required. Also was not asked to show any documents. So I am confused as where did I go wrong.

I am considering to apply again. But what are my chances, as nothing will actually change in my application.

Comment: You should ask the visa officer to explain the specific reasons for the refusal when they tell you, while you are still in the interview in the consulate.

Answer (score 2):

214b is a frustratingly common one, but usually it means you overcome the presumptive intent to immigrate you need to demonstrate, or you didn't meet the required criteria.  [More information on the reasons here](https://www.shanelaw.com/tourism-visas/what-is-a-214b-refusal/).

So applying with the same info is unlikely to help.  You need to see if you didn't meet the criteria - if not, produce it.  If you didn't give enough info showing you will only visit - include more - eg flight tickets, letter from your employer back home, a lease etc.

Comment: OP wasn't even given the Chance to do any of this

Comment: That is a problem. Many who get denied bring all their documents along but they are seldom asked for anything and are directly rejected instead.